# What is this symbol that looks like a double T on an HVAC ductwork diagram?

Tags: hvac, design, planning, architecture

What is this symbol that looks like a double T on an HVAC ductwork diagram?  I've circled the symbol in yellow.  Does the bent L represent some sort of valve?  If it goes through the wall like that, is it some sort of register?  What does the number (100) mean?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can not see it very well on my phone so left as a comment,  that looks like an adjustable damper.

Comment: uploaded a bigger zoomed in picture.

Comment: if it's a damper why does it branch off and does it go through the wall?  The automated dampers are the clear rectangles so this would have to be a different type of damper if it is one?  I noticed the parenthetical numbers are also next to the register grille sizes on the floor above so is this some sort of exhaust?

Comment: Goes to a storage room, so not an exhaust - probably a less-expensive fixed damper for a non-critical conditioned space, rather than a more expensive automatic damper for more lived-in spaces. *i.e.* the whole thing's a duct branch to a register, and the small bit in the middle is probably a fixed damper.

Comment: The drawing shall have a material/equipment list, from which you can find the item which corresponding to item number 100; or find it from the "legend" block on the drawing.

Comment: Looking at the drawings each supply register had a (number) in parenthesis that roughly equaled the sq. footage of the area it was supplying, and it also appeared in the bathroom vent openings as well.  Oddly, the mechanical HVAC drawings were the only ones without a legend, though it did have a title page with other notes and equipment enumerations.  Do builders look at that number to calculate airflow or something?